# Remove underline from DropdownButtonFormField

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I remove the underline from DropdownButtonFormField (check photo below), I have tried various combinations of options with InputDecortaion couldn't find any way.

[image: DropdownButtonFormField]

```
SizedBox(
  width: 100.0,
  child: DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide:
                BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),
    value: 2,
    items: <DropdownMenuItem<int>>[
      DropdownMenuItem<int>(
        value: 1,
        child: Text("Owner"),
      ),
      DropdownMenuItem<int>(
        value: 2,
        child: Text("Member"),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: instead of border Use enabledBorder

Answer (score 66, accepted):

One way of Doing it :

In your Code - change `decoration: InputDecoration` to `decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed`

```
body: SizedBox(
          width: 100.0,
          child: DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
            decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: ''),
            value: 2,
            ...
```

**OR**

In your Code - instead of `border` Use `enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder`

```
DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),
          value: 2,
          items: <DropdownMenuItem<int>>[
          ....
```

Comment: DropdownButtonHideUnderline -> https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/DropdownButtonHideUnderline-class.html

Comment: Doesn't Work in Case of DropdownButtonFormField

Comment: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton()
)

short and sweet,try this one

Comment: Instead of `Colors.white` in `borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),`, `Colors.transparent` is better

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for DropdownButtonFormField, thanks.

Answer (score 187):

Just wrap **DropdownButton** inside **DropdownButtonHideUnderline** like this :

```
new DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
 child: DropdownButton()
)
```

Comment: This is not working for the DropDownButtonFormField widget

Comment: note: your solution works for DropdownButton not DropdownButtonFormField...

Answer (score 108):

Setting the `underline` property to `SizedBox()` makes it invisible too:

```
...

DropdownButton(
  underline: SizedBox(),

...
```

Comment: This only works for DropDownButton, but not DropDownButtonFormField, like the question asked.

Answer (score 32):

The proper/clean solution nowadays is to use `InputBorder.none`:

```dart
DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
    ...
  ),
  ...
)
```

You might also want to set `border`, `focusedBorder`, `errorBorder`, and `disabledBorder` to `InputBorder.none` if you want to avoid the border from showing in all cases.

Answer (score 28):

underline can take a widget so, you just have assigned it an empty Container, or a SizedBox.shrink()

```
                  underline:Container(),
                         -- or --
                  underline:SizedBox.shrink(),
```

Example :

```
child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  // Just have to assign to a empty Container
                  underline:Container(),
                  value: dropdownValue,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                  iconSize: 24,
                  elevation: 16,
                  onChanged: (String newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      dropdownValue = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                  items:[
                    deptList[0].dept,
                    deptList[1].dept,
                    deptList[2].dept,
                    deptList[3].dept,
                  ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                )
```

Comment: underline:Container(), work for DropDownButton, Please reply for DropdownbuttonFormField

Answer (score 6):

As of now, DropdownButtonFormField doesn't support DropdownButtonHideUnderline.

*Although it uses it under the hood to remove the underline from DropdownButton but then applies it's own decoration on top of that*

Setting border to InputBorder.none will do the job

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
  decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none)
)
```

If you want the border to appear on error you can use

```
InputDecoration(
  border: InputBorder.none,
  errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 5):

You can change underline property to blank or null widget it will work like charm check the below property

**underline**: widget or SizedBox(),

Ex:-
DropdownButton(
icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
isExpanded: true,
value: dropValue,
**underline**: widget or SizedBox(),

Answer (score 5):

Add `underline: Container()` to your settings like this:

```dart
SizedBox(
   ...
   underline: Container(),
),
```

Answer (score 5):

According to this [Flutter Doc] You can do like this. Simply create an object of **DropdownButtonHideUnderline** class and pass your current implementation of the  **DropdownButton** as the child of DropdownButtonHideUnderline. Thts it ;)

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: new DropdownButton<String>(
            ......
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 4):

Easy  Way to do it:

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
      ),
    ),
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
DropdownButton<String>(
                    hint: Text("Status"),
                    value: 'Text Default',
                    isExpanded: true,
                    iconSize: 30,
                    underline: Container(
                      height: 1.0,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0.0))
                      ),
                    ),
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                      child: DropdownButton(
                         isExpanded: true,
                      hint: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text("Select State"),
                      ),
                      style: MyStyle().getTextStyle("x1black"),
                      items: <String>[
                        'Messaging',
                        'Chating',
                        'No Longer Interested',
                        'Document Request'
                      ].map((String value) {
                        return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: new Text(value),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (_) {},
                      ),

                    ),
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answering questions is good but this answer is just badly formatted code with no explanation. The code is similar to code in other answers. A good and useful answer has an explanation and provides new insights into the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Underline takes a Widget. Pass it a blank widget, like below.

```
DropdownButton<T>(
  value: value,
  underline: SizeBox(), // Empty box will remove underline
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following code:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
)
```

To disable every border on the width, set **InputBorder.none** for **border attribute**. Or if you prefer to disable only the border when dropdown is enable, set for **enabledBorder**.

Answer (score 1):

if DropdownButtonFormField text get trim due to outline border then use this code:

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                                  isDense: true,)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: ButtonTheme(
                    alignedDropdown: false,
                    splashColor: Colors.grey,
                    child: DropdownButton<String>(
                      value: _myPargna,
                      iconSize: 25,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                      style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Color(0xFF1f193d)),
                      hint: Row(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(width: 11),
                          Text(
                            'Select Province',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      onChanged: (String newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          _myPargna = newValue;
                        });
                      },
                      items: items.map((String items) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(width: 12),
                              Text(
                                items,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          value: items,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just Do this

```
decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  // enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                  // disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                  // focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                  // errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
              iconSize: 30,
              decoration: InputDecoration(enabledBorder: InputBorder.none),
              hint: Text(
                "Select Duration",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              items: listDrop,
              onChanged: (value) {
                duration = value;
              },
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want just disable the border in all the case you can use :

```
 DropdownButtonFormField(
                validator: _validator,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                 ),
                items: [],
                onChanged: (value) {}),
          ),
```

if you want disable only when there is no error you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64644178/6266012)

Answer (score 0):

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: kLightBlackColor)),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me**

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
border: InputBorder.none,
```